# How to delete my old images located in the bundle during an update?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, sdk, bundle

I make an application with images *.png placed directly in the bundle.
In an update, when I delete an image from the project, it remains in my application! 
How to completely remove this image ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "update", do you mean an update via the appstore or just a recompilation on your machine?

Answer (score 3):

If it's the simulator, you need to completely delete the app from the simulator.  Xcode isn't super smart about removing non-referenced PNG's and other resources from the built products folder.

If it's the device, then you probably simply need to clean your project's targets (under Xcode's "Build" menu) and then do a new build & install onto the device.

Comment: Right, it works on the simulator by removing the application. In fact, I would like to know for an update via itunes.

Comment: Would have been nice if you had specified that in your original question. Also, update via iTunes of your archive or .ipa file or update of an app via accessing the Apple App Store in iTunes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant update of an app via accessing the Apple App Store in iTunes.

Comment: That's *really* strange that an app store update doesn't completely erase the previous application's bundle while updating (since updates have to be code-signed and if any files or resources are out of place, the app isn't supposed to be able to run). If you are trying to populate some scroll view with all images within a folder hidden in your bundle, consider *copying* those images to a clean cache folder external to your app bundle (that way you only pick up exactly the images you want to display and not any accidentally inserted ones).